# How to remove the first node and insert it at the end of a linked list C++?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to figure out how to remove the first node and insert it at the end of a linked.So far I was able to add each character of "Hello" to the linked list and added a "-" at the end of the list.I am trying to figure out how to implement the rotate function on my list.h.

list.h:

```
   class list{
    private:
        node *head;
        node *tail;
    public:

        list(){
            head = NULL;
            tail = NULL;
        }

         ~list(){
            if(head == NULL){
                return;
            }
            node *temp = head;
            while(temp != NULL){
                node *next = temp ->next;
                delete temp;
                temp = next;
            }
        }

        void addAtEnd(char x){
            node *temp = new node(x);
            node *curr = head;
            if(head = NULL){
                head = temp;
            }else{
                while(curr->next != NULL){
                   curr = curr->next;
                }
                curr ->next = temp;
            }
        }
        bool isVowel(char ch)
        {
            switch (ch)
            {
                case 'A':
                case 'E':
                case 'I':
                case 'O':
                case 'U':
                case 'Y':
                case 'a':
                case 'e':
                case 'i':
                case 'o':
                case 'u':
                case 'y':
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
                }
        }

        void rotate(){
            node *temp = head;
            if(isVowel(temp->n)){
               addAtEnd('-');


            } 
        }
```

Comment: There are [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) in the C++ Standard Library. This _struct wiring_ is something C developers, academia and bad C++ technical interviewers are more fond of.

Comment: Set the head pointer to the next element and point the tail pointer at the head pointer. That is not a rotation though, that's just a swap of the head and tail.

Comment: @rpg711 That comment is a good example of how updating variables and then using them can confuse programmers about which value it currently holds.  Following it literally would orphan the node. Write `node * const rotated = head;` and it will not be ambiguous which node is `rotated`.

Comment: Looked like homework, I was intentionally vague so the op could figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move first element from a single-linked list to the end you have to:

```
// Moves one element of a single-linked list from the front to the back
void rotate() {
    if (head && head != tail ) {
        node* tmp = head;            // Store a reference to the first element
        head = head->next;           // Set the head of the list to the second element
        tmp->next = nullptr;         // Detach the removed element from the list
        tail->next = tmp;            // Link the last element to the removed element
        tail = tmp;                  // and update the tail
    }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4d322e13ff655f7

You have to update `tail` in `addAtEnd()` so you can use it. Otherwise you always have to iterate through the list to find the tail nide.